# JQuery unable to validate password complexity

Tags: jquery, passwords, password-protection

i'm trying to perform validation for password complexity and would like to ensure that the textbox is not empty, has at-least 1 letter, 1 number and 1 special character. somehow even when entering a password satisfying the criteria, the true case message block does not execute. What am i missing here?

```
$("#textbox1").focusout(function()
{
    var fn = $('#textbox1').val();
    if ((fn=="") || (/^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test(fn) == false) || (/^[0-9]*$/.test(fn) == false) || (/^[!@#$%^&*() ]*$/.test(fn)==false))
    {
        /*execute error messages*/
    }
    else
    {
       /*execute true case messages*/
    }
});
```

Comment: The code as pasted has a syntax error:

    > (/^[a-zA- ]*$/.test(fn)==false)
    VM118:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[a-zA- ]*$/: Range out of order in character class

Comment: hi david, just updated the code after reading your comment. i'm still stuck with the same problem though.

Comment: Try debugging . Check in console for every condition of if that whether the test function is actually returning the right boolean .

Comment: I think you will find that no string will pass all of the traps. Not all of them, and maybe none of them, should have start (^) and finish ($) identifiers.